# Automatic execution of code after finishing a cell in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter

Is it possible to set up Jupyter so that whenever a cell is finished running it would automatically carry out some code?

Some of my code takes a long time to run, and it is quite inconvenient to have to check back often to see whether the code is completed. I can manually add some notification code at the end of each cell, but it would be much easier if I can simply put this code in say, `jupyter_application_config.py` or `custom.js`, and have jupyter calls it automatically.

It would be even better if it can be set up so that the code is executed if the cell takes more than n seconds to run.

Comment: Have a look at the Notify extension from [IPython-notebook-extensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/IPython-notebook-extensions). It will pop up a browser notification when the kernel finishes after running for a somewhat-configurable number of seconds. To do this programmatically, I suppose you could look at the extension's implementation for some ideas on how to go about it.

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late... but I also wanted notifications when long running code in Jupyter cells had completed, and I found the Notify extension to be limiting (eg., no notifications if I was away from my computer). My solution for myself was to create a custom magic that using Pushbullet to send notifications to both my computer and my iPhone.

The magic is called [pushnote](https://github.com/nick-youngblut/pushnote). Maybe it will be helpful for you.